# NSNotification Observer added in viewWillAppear is executed twice in iOS 13

Tags: ios, ios13, nsnotifications

I came across a strange problem when handling a `NSNotification` iOS 13

```
// Adding the observer in viewWillAppear
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ...
    NSLog(@"Adding observer");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification) name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
    NSLog(@"Removed observer");
}

- (void)handleNotification {
    NSLog(@"Handle notification");
}
```

I have double checked that the notification is posted only **once**. There is only one place in the app where `someNotification` is posted and a breakpoint and `NSLog` confirms, that this code is only executed once.

**Result in iOS 12 and below:**

```
Adding observer
Handle notification
```

**Result in iOS 13 and below:**

```
Adding observer
Handle notification
Handle notification
```

So in iOS 13 the observer is called twice while the exact same code in iOS 12 and blow is only called once.

My first guess was, that for some reason in iOS 13 `viewWillAppear` is called twice that thus the observer is added twice. However, in this case the `NSLog` output `Adding Observer` should also appear twice, **shouldn't it?**

**BUT:** The problem can be solved by removing the observer in `viewWillAppear` before adding it. This makes sure, that the observer is added only once:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ...
    NSLog(@"Adding observer");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification) name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
}
```

So, since this solves the problem the observer obviously **is added twice** in `viewWillAppear`. But why?

**Why is `viewWillAppear` called twice in iOS 13? And even more important: How is it possible, that it is called twice but the `NSLog` output `Adding Observer` appears only once?**

Comment: What notification is your observer observing? That event - whatever it is - is happening twice on iOS 13 and once on iOS 12. I think that is what you need to look into. viewWillAppear() is not called twice.

Comment: As said in the question "I have double checked that the notification is posted only once. There is only one place in the app where someNotification is posted and a breakpoint and NSLog confirms, that this code is only executed once.". Even if I would have missed something and the notification would be posted twice, removing the observer in `viewWillAppear` before adding it should have no effect. But is has an effect, it solves the problem... Thus I can be sure, that the notification is posted only once, can't I?

Comment: It seems that on iOS 13 viewWillDisappear() is not called. Is this an iPad? Or, rather are you loading this view controller twice perhaps as child view controllers of another?

Comment: This is happening both on iPhone and on iPad. It is correct that `viewWillDisappear()` but this is intended. I have only included this in my question to provide a complete example of the notification observation lifecycle.

Comment: Is your class possibly a subclass of another class and does this superclass also somehow registers a notification of "someNotification"?

Comment: @vilmoskörte No, just a direct `UIViewController` subclass. So the parent class does not use the custom `someNotification` message. Do you mean an observer of this notification or a *sender*. As said before I double check that the notification is posted only once and even if I missed something, removing the observer before adding it should have no effect (but it has). Thus I can be sure that the notification is posted only once.

Comment: How is "someNotification" declared?

Comment: What do you mean by how `someNotification` is declared? It is just a string to identify the notification.